# How long does it take to load FormCalc package?

Tags: packages, feyncalc

I've installed the package (FeynArts, LoopTools, and FormCalc) via FeynInstall.

Then, I load the package by

```
<<FeynArts`
<<FormCalc`
```

I get message

```
FeynArts 3.9 (23 Sep 2015)
by Hagen Eck, Sepp Kueblbeck, and Thomas Hahn
FormCalc 9.4 (7 Jun 2016)
by Thomas Hahn
```

But it's still keep running (evaluating).

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could you include the operating system and Mathematica version you are using.  Maybe you might want to contact the author of these packages?

Comment: My OS is Windows 10 with Mathematica 9.0. If no one could help me with this problem, I agree that I have to contact the author directly.